# can't call performseguewithidentifier from UITableViewCell

Tags: swift

I can't call performseguewithidentifier in Infinite3TableViewCell class inside. i knew it is UITableViewCell.
So, How can call performseguewithidentifier method in Infinite3TableViewCell?

I want to select a cell then present/segue to new ViewController.

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
final class BuyTableViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    }
}
```

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
extension BuyTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 5
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0, 1, 2, 3, 4: return 1
    default: return 0
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.section {

    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Infinite0TableViewCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: InfiniteTableViewCell.identifier) as! InfiniteTableViewCell
        return cell
    case 2:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Infinite2TableViewCell.identifier) as! Infinite2TableViewCell
        return cell
    case 3:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Infinite3TableViewCell.identifier) as! Infinite3TableViewCell
        return cell
    case 4:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Infinite4TableViewCell.identifier) as! Infinite4TableViewCell
        return cell
    default:
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0: return 80
    case 1: return 150
    case 2: return 120
    case 3: return 400
    case 4: return 500
    default: return 0
    }
```

final class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var imgEffect: UIVisualEffectView!
```

final class Infinite3TableViewCell: UITableViewCell  {

```
static let identifier = "Infinite3TableViewCell"


var nameArray = ["Women's Clothing", "Beauty & Personl Care", "Women's Bags", "Men's Clothing", "Mobile & Gadgets", "Watches", "Home", "Toys", "Home Appliances"]
var imgName = [UIImage(named: "girl"), UIImage(named: "makeup"), UIImage(named: "bags"), UIImage(named: "clothing"), UIImage(named: "mobile"), UIImage(named: "watches"), UIImage(named: "living"), UIImage(named: "toys"), UIImage(named: "tools")]
```

extension Infinite3TableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    return nameArray.count

}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{



    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imgImage.image = imgName[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblName.text! = nameArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell


}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    print("didSelectItemAt: \(indexPath.item)")
```

Comment: Please only post relevant code (and please format it properly).

Comment: Why do you want to call `performseguewithidentifier` from within the table view cell? The cell does not directly know when it has been clicked. You would know when a cell is clicked from the `UITableView` delegate method `didSelectRowAt` and that would be the logical place to call the segue from.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm sorry. Because I first time use stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`performseguewithidentifier` should be called from a `UIViewController` or its subclass. You should let the `UIViewController` know and call it.

Comment: So, how should I do?

Comment: Call `performseguewithidentifier ` in `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` in your `BuyTableViewController`

Comment: if I put didSelectItemAt in BuyTableViewController. when i click the tableview 3 in cell, how the system know i click it? @aahung

[link](http://imgh.us/Screen_Shot_2017-03-21_at_1.24.08_PM.png)

Comment: What does "tableview 3 in cell mean"? If you set the tableview's delegate to BuyTableViewController, the when you select a cell it will know